# How do I sum horizontally across a row based on 1st column value?

Tags: google-sheets

I've used the search but haven't found much on this.  Essentially I would like to do a `SUMIF` style action on a dataset but it only grabs the first adjacent value.  My table would be something like:

```
KT    4    5    9
AM    3    7    8
IA    2    5   12
```

On rows below I would have

```
KT |  =Sumif(A1:E3,A8,B1:E3)   Which returns 4
AM |  =Sumif(A1:E3,A9,B1:E3)   Which returns 3
IA |  =Sumif(A1:E3,A8,B1:E3)   Which returns 2
```

Now I know I could surely just add a column with a total use `vlookup(array, value, index)` but that is not what I want to do (although I may just do so if this is too big a pain).

Any thoughts/ideas.  Demo [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pg1sdXm4IUrKU4NDLUSibvfaPnXF-TbBevt2u4RPgNI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Sumif` wont work... :( Do as Jerry says below, or use `=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$E$3*($A$1:$A$3=A8))`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the 'VLOOKUP` similarity:

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$1:$E$3, MATCH(A8, $A$1:$A$3, 0), 0))
```

`INDEX($B$1:$E$3, MATCH(A8, $A$1:$A$3, 0), 0)` returns the row within `$B$1:$E$3` where the range `$A$1:$A$3` corresponds to A8.

Comment: Thanks, I find it odd that sumif works for vertical series but not horizontal ones.

Comment: @Kevrone No problem. `SUMIF` works for horizontal ranges too, it's just that it's one column or one row at a time, not multiple rows/columns.